Getting VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_PRE_MULTIPLIED_BIT_KHR working on Windows
I found a post asking about the same question:
Vulkan and transparent windows
However, the person asking the question wasn't checking whether VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_PRE_MULTIPLIED_BIT_KHR was supported. I am checking this, and it definitely shows that it isn't supported. When I call vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR and check if .supportedCompositeAlpha has the VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_PRE_MULTIPLIED_BIT_KHR bit set, it always returns false.
I am using API 1.3 with the latest Vulkan driver on Windows 10. I find it strange that it's not supported, but someone in the other question suggested that it might have something to do with the way the window is created. I tried the following code:
hwnd_ = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_LAYERED,
    name_.c_str(),
    window_title.c_str(),
    dwStyle, // | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN
    0,
    0,
    window_rect.right - window_rect.left,
    window_rect.bottom - window_rect.top,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    hinstance_,
    nullptr);

if (!hwnd_) {
    std::cerr << "Can't create a window" << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
}

SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd_, 0, 255, LWA_ALPHA); // for transparent surface

I am using WS_EX_LAYERED and SetLayeredWindowAttributes, which I understand are necessary to get a window with adjustable opacity. However, this makes no difference.

The initial post I am referring to doesn't explain if there's something that needs to be done on the Window creation process side that could change the surface properties in such a way that this flag would be on.

There's no information as to yes or no Nvidia and/or AMD support that feature. If so is this written somewhere, can this be found.


I wonder if this issue is controlled by the driver or related to the way the Windows window is created. Has anyone gotten it working? If so, could you share your code for the Windows window creation?

The proper way to have a render target control the alpha transparency of a window is by creating it with the WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP extended window style. This cuts out the middle man but requires creating a composition render target. This is exposed via the DirectComposition API on Windows. You'll have to investigate whether Vulkan can interop with Windows' swapchain/composition infrastructure.

@IInspectable thank you so much. Someone told me about the direct composition approach. Yes it seems like the DirectComposition approach uses DirectX and so somehow I will need a way to interop. But you confirmed a path I was about to explore. Thanks a lot.
